# how to add some selected items and their indexes from listbox to datatable

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, listbox

I`m trying to use something like this:
I have 20 list items and I have to choose some of them, then add them to datatable in first column elements, in second - their indexes.

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      dt.Columns.Add("Фактор-Критерій", typeof(string));
      dt.Columns.Add("Ранг", typeof(string));

      ChoosenCriteria.DataSource = dt;
        List<string> selectedItems = new List<string>();
        foreach (string o in listBox1.SelectedItems)
            selectedItems.Add(o);
        List<int> selectedItemIndexes = new List<int>();
        foreach (int o in listBox1.SelectedIndices)
            selectedItemIndexes.Add(listBox1.Items.IndexOf(o));
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr[0] = selectedItems.ToString();
            dr[1] = selectedItemIndexes.ToString();
            dt.Rows.Add(dr););
```

I can not do this, all i have at the end is on screen:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEvzo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Move the `DataSource` binding statement after you have done with the modification like

```
for(int i=0; i<selectedItems.Count;i++
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr[0] = selectedItems[i].ToString();
    dr[1] = selectedItemIndexes[i].ToString();
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
ChoosenCriteria.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: I was trying this but It doesn`t change anything.
I think the problem is in the list because it is transformed to one line with:

Comment: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Comment: @LidiyaZahurska, my bad, try the edited code in answer. You were performing a `ToString()` on the entire collection rather you need a item from the collection.

Comment: Thank you,this helped me a lot.

Comment: @LidiyaZahurska, consider accepting the answer then by clicking the check button under voting button.